# Wireless adapter failing during bootup

Tags: boot, networking, wireless

I am running a dual boot Windows 7/14.04. I previously used an ethernet connection but after moving apartments it is more convenient for me to use a wireless adapter (ASUS PCE-AC55BT). Now, when I boot Ubuntu, I see the following sequence.

- At the beginning of bootup (after selecting Ubuntu), I get a message 'ACPI PCC probe failed'
- Next, I get the message "Waiting for network configuration" and then "Waiting another 60 seconds for network configuration"
- After ubuntu boots there is an approximately 2 minute delay during which time I have no wireless network connection. After this time, the connection works great (which means I don't think it is a network manager issue). This correction in behavior corresponds to syslog showing the device being mounted:

  ```
  Oct  8 12:18:26 pt-5810 udisksd[2315]: Cleaning up mount point /media/myname/ASUS PCE-AC55BT (device 11:0 is not mounted)
  Oct  8 12:18:26 pt-5810 udisksd[2315]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
  Oct  8 12:18:29 pt-5810 kernel: [  149.322478] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3Oct  8 12:18:29 pt-5810 kernel: [  149.327421] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
  Oct  8 12:18:29 pt-5810 udisksd[2315]: Mounted /dev/sr0 at /media/myname/ASUS PCE-AC55BT on behalf of uid 1000
  Oct  8 12:18:29 pt-5810 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x56a2bb57)
  Oct  8 12:18:46 pt-5810 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x56a2bb57)
  Oct  8 12:19:01 pt-5810 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x56a2bb57)
  ```

How can I address the issue such that I am not waiting 4-5 minutes everytime that I boot my machine? For example, Is there anyway I can have the wireless card device mount happen during the boot process?

Other info:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep Network
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev bb)

lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network | grep Kernel
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Many thanks

Comment: You can try adding `iwlwifi` to /etc/modules, and you can assure that your connection is WPA2-AES. Also make sure in your wireless profile, that `automatically connect` and `all users` are enabled in the general tab. See if that helps. Cheers, Al

Comment: ps: the mount information that you see in your syslog is from a secondary hard disk that you're trying to mount (not the wireless adapter) and it may have an unclean filesystem. You may need to do an fsck or chkdsk on it to clean it up. You also have a CD/DVD mounting at boot time. Cheers, Al